# Saltstack jinja2 natural sort

Tags: python, jinja2, salt-stack

I have pillar.example:

```
dnsmasq:
  zones:
    domain_com:
      hosts:
        1.1.1.1: host1
        1.1.1.2: host2
        1.1.1.3: host3
        1.1.1.21: host21
```

And my sls:

```
{% for zone in pillar['dnsmasq']['zones'] %}

/tmp/{{ zone }}:
  file.managed:
    - contents:
{% for ip, host in pillar['dnsmasq']['zones'][zone]['hosts']|dictsort  %}
           {{ ip }} {{ host }}
{% endfor %}
{% endfor %}
```

This produces:

```
# cat /tmp/domain_com
1.1.1.1 host1
1.1.1.2 host2
1.1.1.21 host21
1.1.1.3 host3
```

How does one use human/natural sorting in saltstack so my file would be like:

```
# cat /tmp/domain_com
1.1.1.1 host1
1.1.1.2 host2
1.1.1.3 host3
1.1.1.21 host21
```

Comment: Do you want to have everything in one pillar file? Another simple solution would be to just place a file on the master and refer to this file from your pillar - you can sort this however you want and everything would be 'green' :)

Answer (score 0):

Looks like you need to write a [custom filter](https://docs.saltstack.com/en/latest/topics/jinja/index.html#custom-jinja-filters) as there seems to be nothing that fits your need out of the box.

Or you call bash for rescue and execute `cat /tmp/domain_com | sort -n > cat /tmp/domain_com` afterwards using `cmd.run` together with `require`. It makes the state a little messy, but keeps things in place. I'd prefer this approach.

**untested example**

```
{% for zone in pillar['dnsmasq']['zones'] %}

/tmp/{{ zone }}:
  file.managed:
    - contents:
{% for ip, host in pillar['dnsmasq']['zones'][zone]['hosts'] %}
       {{ ip }} {{ host }}
{% endfor %}

cat /tmp/{{ zone }} | sort -n > /tmp/{{ zone }}:
  cmd.run:
    - require:
      - file: /tmp/{{ zone }}
{% endfor %}
```

Comment: Thanks for responding; I did try this before, it worked... but not like in your example as there will be no file to cat/sort on the first execution (jinja comes first)
Sorting the file afterwards is a bit of a catch22, as salt will always be updating the file on the next highstate/state.sls, so the output will never be 'green'.

Comment: Well, in this case you need to pick the other approach mentioned in the first sentence. Or give this slightly modifier version using `onchanges` a try.

Comment: forget about it - there would always be changes if you do it like that...